# Javascript push on a localStorage item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried too many question solutions from stack overflow but still i can't solve this issue and i have no idea where i'm going wrong this thing as i'm new to JavaScript coding.

Here is the code:

```
function SaveFavMovie(id)
{

let movies = moviesData.movies;
let movieid = -1;
for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    if (movies[i].id === id) {
        movieid = id;
    }
}
if(!movieid) return;

var a = [];
a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moviedb'));
a.push(id); 
localStorage.setItem('moviedb', JSON.stringify(a));
return true;
```

Here is the error get from the above code

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.push is not a function
at Object.SaveFavMovie
```

This is the line it shows the error

```
a.push(tmp);
```

The webstore 'moviedb' is empty and trying to push data for first time.

Comment: `JSON.parse` returns an Object, not an array. There's no push method

Comment: @Skwal So How to keep pushing to web storage if you want to add new id to the same item in web storage?

Comment: It depends what information you wanna store. If it's a simple array of ids like your code suggests, then you should be fine as long as your storage is not empty, and Jonas already gave a good answer to fix it. Try adding a `console.log(a)` after your JSON.parse line, you'll see what you get from the storage.

Answer (score 4):

```
 a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moviedb'));
```

If the entry does not exist in localStorage (yet), it cannot parse anything and will therefore set a to `null`. And thats not an array. So in the case that it is not stored yet, you might wanna take an array instead:

```
 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moviedb')) || [];
```

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: It should work. `getItem()` will return null if the storage is empty. `JSON.parse(null)` is valid and will also return null, therefore it will fallback to the `|| []`.